# React function from context does not invoke in children

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have this context:

```
// contexts/auth.tsx

import {createContext, useState, useContext} from "react";
import type {User} from "../types";

type Context = {
  user: User | null;
  login: () => void;
  logout: () => void;
};

const AuthContext = createContext<Context>({
  user: null,
  login: () => {console.log("hey")}, // This works
  logout: () => {},
});

export function useAuth() {
  return useContext(AuthContext);
}

export const AuthProvider: React.FC = ({children}) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<User | null>(null);

  // This does not work
  function login() {
    console.log("Logging in...");
    setUser({
      id: "1",
      name: "User One",
    });
  }

  // This does not work
  function logout() {
    console.log("Logging out...");
    setUser(null);
  }

  const value = {user, login, logout};

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

And this is the test page:

```
// pages/test.tsx

import {AuthProvider, useAuth} from "../contexts/auth";

export default function Test() {
  const {user, login, logout} = useAuth();
  console.log("user:", user); // Returns null

  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <div>

          {/* Returns `hey` */}
          <button onClick={login}>
            Log in
          </button>

          <button onClick={logout}>
            Log out
          </button>

      </div>
    </AuthProvider>
  );
}
```

When I click Log in button in test page, it logs `hey`. But I expected to log `Loggin in...` and set `user` object.

What am I doing wrong?

I am using react.js v17.0.2, next.js v11.0.1, TypeScript v4.3.5.

Comment: You're consuming the context outside the custom provider. To use the context that has the custom value in your test page, you need to wrap `<TestPage />` in the provider in the parent's JSX: https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-kowalevski-9106e?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Thank you @ChrisG. It works now. Would you like to turn this answer? So that I can mark it as accepted.